# Why do Germans duschen instead of schauer?

Tags: etymology

I recently learned that in German, one uses the (I thought french) word “Dusche” to describe what in English would be called “taking a shower”.  Meanwhile, the English word *shower* is apparently Germanic, comparable to *Schauer*.

**Why do Germans say "duschen" instead of "schauern"?**

Comment: Because they're not afraid of water.

Comment: Beim Duschen schauern die Deutschen normalerweise nicht. See https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schauern.

Comment: English and German separated about 1500 years ago, so it's no wonder that they use different words for the same thing, even when the words are of Germanic origin.

Comment: You could also ask why the English do not (usually) [douche](https://www.etymonline.com/word/douche).

Comment: Why do Germans not say *spritzbaden*? I mean, they could.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is so surprising about French loanwords in German language? English has lots of French loanwords too. Wikipedia decided to list them in four separate articles, because they are so many: [A-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin_(A%E2%80%93C)), [D-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin_(D%E2%80%93I)), [J-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin_(J%E2%80%93R)), [S-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_French_origin_(S%E2%80%93Z)). So German also has a lot of French loanwords: [Wikipedia: Gallizismen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Gallizismen)

---

**die Dusche** (noun); **duschen** (verb)
Before 19th century nobody used to shower. It came into German vocabulary as a medical term in 18th century, and became part of common language only in 19th century, when at first time people began to shower. Only rich people could afford the infrastructure and also public institutions. So for most people *duschen* or *brausen* (see below) was something that you could only do in a public bath. The word *brausen* was the term that was used by common people, *duschen* was used by aristocrats and other rich people who could afford to shower at home.

After WW II it became more and more common to have a shower at home, so in second half of 20th century both terms (*brausen, duschen*) was used side by side. Now (since the end of 20th century) *duschen* is the primary term and *brausen* is a less used synonym.

The French word *douche* has its origin in the Italian word *doccia* which means *gutter* or *trench* or *channel*. This word again is derived from Latin *ductio* which is a noun that means something like *the tug, the lead*. The corresponding verb is *ducere* (*to tug, to pull, to lead*)

---

**die Brause** (noun); **brausen** (verb)
These words have the same meaning as *Dusche* and *duschen,* but they have a different origin. Their origin is not very clear. Many experts think it is an onomatopoetic word that describes the sound of a waterfall, so it is similar to the English word *swoosh*. Also discussed is a relation to the noun *Braus* which today is only used in the phrase *»in Saus und Braus«* which means *"in the lap of luxury"*. But I think the onomatopoetic root is correct (my personal opinion).
Since the verb reflects to the sound, it also can be used when something makes a similar noise:

> Dieter **brauste** in seinem Ferrari an uns vorbei.
>   Dieter **rushed** past us in his Ferrari.

btw: German *brausen* is neither etymologically related to English *to browse*, nor have these words a common meaning. (They are *"false friends".*)

As told in the section above, *brausen* was something that you did in a public bath. I lived for a long time in Vienna, and there are still some of those *Brausebäder*:
[image: Städtisches Brausebad]
The heading over the door in this picture says »municipal shower bath«.

---

**der Schauer** (noun); **schauern** (verb)
A *Schauer* is a short stormy rain, but also a suddenly and intense sensation of fear and horror. It was in Middle High German *»schur«* and Old High German *»scur«.* It's meaning was all the time *storm, hail, short and intense rain.*
Since there is no frightening thunderstorm in your bathroom when you take a shower, German speaking people never had the idea to give their *Brause* or *Dusche* such a negative connoted name.

Comment: The french taught us about some basic hygiene in 1st place it seems.

Comment: **Die Brause** has an additional meaning that Hubert, being Austrian, probably is not aware of: it is another word for lemonade https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brause

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Das Brausepulver heißt auch in Österreich *Brausepulver.* Aber ein kohlensäurehaltiges Getränk hieß in Österreich (und soweit mir bekannt ist auch in Bayern) lange Zeit *Kracherl.* Vor dem 1. Weltkrieg waren die Flaschen, in denen das teure Getränk verkauft wurde, mit einer Glaskugel verschlossen, die durch den Innendruck der Flasche nach oben in den Flaschenhals gedrückt wurde. Diese Kugel musste man eindrücken um die Flasche zu öffnen, dabei entstand ein krachendes Geräusch, und daher kam der Name *Kracherl.* Heute spricht man von *Soft Drink* oder *Limonade.*